# How to use ui-select within inline form of Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ui-select

I'm facing multiple issues while using ui-select within a bootsrap inline form:
http://plnkr.co/edit/tAlsDona9LS8D6KUQziS?p=preview

```
<form class="form-inline"> ... </form>
```

1. Within form-group, label and ui-select are not inline, even if there are plenty place for it.
2. Caret and text are overlapping.
3. Long content overflows[image]
4. Short content displays strange background [image]

Please, take a look at my plunk, and enlighten me, what am I doing wring?

Comment: Plnkr doesn't want to load for me. Are you using a Bootstrap theme for ui-select? If not, you'll have to dig in and set some CSS overrides to clear up the default styling.

Comment: Whole plunkr.co seems "down" for me too at the moment... please try again in a few minutes, hope it loads. And yes, i use: theme="bootstrap".

Comment: In that case, it would be helpful to see your HTML here.

Comment: Plunker should be up by now, please try again: http://plnkr.co/edit/tAlsDona9LS8D6KUQziS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14272) information about this style: they set the control in the form-inline to use width auto.

You could write your own class to override that behavior as they suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592969/boostrap-3-1-1-nav-bar-maximized-input-no-longer-maximized-in-3-2-0).